# Type-casting and getting an array to peek generic results

Tags: java, arrays, types, casting

I am writing a program that inherits some traits from MyStackGeneric called MyStackInteger. I am almost done with the assignment, but I am running into an issue. As soon as I get my two variables in the method binaryOperator, it tries to add, subtract or multiply strings which returns and error. I've tried type casting and moving things around but I cannot get it to work. One of the constraints of my work is that all the methods that are currently in MyStackGeneric have to stay in there. I cannot have them in MyStackInteger as we are going to be using this for Complex numbers in the future.

```
class `MyStackInteger`:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MyStackInteger extends MyStackGeneric<java.lang.Integer>{

//Creates a new ArrayList and runs readInput as long as there is input
public static void main(String[] args){
  MyStackInteger my = new MyStackInteger(){};
  my.readInput(new Scanner(System.in));
}

//Subtracts two variables
@Override
protected java.lang.Integer minus(java.lang.Integer o1, java.lang.Integer o2){
    o2 = o2-o1;
    return o2;
}

//Multiplies two variables
@Override
protected java.lang.Integer multiply(java.lang.Integer o1, java.lang.Integer o2){
    o2 = o2*o1;
    return o2;
}

//Creates a new element in the Array
@Override
protected java.lang.Integer newElement(java.lang.String w){
    return new Integer(w);
}

//Adds two variables
@Override
protected java.lang.Integer plus(java.lang.Integer o1, java.lang.Integer o2){
    o2 = o2+o1;
    return o2;
}

//Adds a zero to the array
@Override
protected java.lang.Integer zero(){
    Integer blank = 0;
    return blank;
}
}

class MyStackGeneric<E>:

abstract class MyStackGeneric<E> extends ArrayList<E>{

//Generics being implemented by MyStackInteger
protected abstract E multiply(E o1, E o2);

protected abstract E minus(E o1, E o2);

protected abstract E plus(E o1, E o2);

protected abstract E zero();

protected abstract E newElement(java.lang.String w);

//Grabs the top element of the ArrayList
public E peek(){
   return this.get(getSize()-1);
}  

//Removes the top element of the ArrayList
public E pop(){
    E o = this.get(getSize()-1);
    this.remove(getSize()-1);
    return o;
} 

//Pushes an element onto the ArrayList
public void push(E o) {
    this.add(o);
}

//Makes the ListArray A string
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "stack: " + this.toString();
}   

//Iterates while there is input
public void readInput(Scanner s) {
    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String s2 = s.next();
            //Pushes any numerical input to the stack
            if (s2.matches("[+-]?\\d+")) {
                push((E) s2);
            //Goes to binaryOperator if +, - or * is implemented
            } else if (("+".equals(s2)) || 
                      ("-".equals(s2)) || 
                      ("*".equals(s2))) {
                binaryOperator(s2);
            //Prints the stack
            } else if (s2.matches("p")) {
                print();
            //Runs an error if the input is too long
            } else if (s2.length() > 1) {
                System.out.println("Exception: too long: " + s2);
            //Runs an error if there is one unknown char
            } else if (s2.length() == 1) {
                System.out.println("Exception: Unknown Command " + s2);
            }

    }
}

//Prints the stack
public void print(){
   System.out.println("Print Stack: ");
   Iterator<E> s = this.iterator();

   while(s.hasNext()){
       System.out.print(s.next() + (s.hasNext() ? ", " : "\n" ));
   System.out.println("");
   }
}

//Checks if the ArrayList is empty
public boolean empty(){
    return this.isEmpty();
}

//Gets the total size of the ArrayList
public int getSize(){
    return this.size();
}

//Tries to grab the top two elements of the ArrayList, then execute a 
//arithmetic operation on them.
public void binaryOperator(java.lang.String op){
    E var1; 
    E var2;
    boolean exist = true;
    try {
        var1 = peek();
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: Need two operands");
        var1 = null;
        exist = false;
    }
    if (exist)
       pop();
    try {
        var2 = peek();
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: Need two operands");
        var2 = null;
        exist = false;
    }
    if (exist)
        pop();
    //This is where the program breaks. At this point, both var1
    //and var2 are Strings so when it tries to run plus or minus
    //or multiply, it returns the error of not being able to turn
    //a string into an int.
    if ("+".equals(op)){
       push(plus(var1, var2));
    }
    if ("-".equals(op)){
       push(minus(var1, var2));
    }
    if ("*".equals(op)){
       push(multiply(var1, var2));
    }  
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        if (s2.matches("[+-]?\\d+")) {
            push((E) s2);
```

You cannot do this.  You cannot take a `String` and execute an arbitrary cast on it.  If you were paying attention to the compiler you would see the warning message

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from String to E
```

The primary issue is with your design. The method `readInput` has no business being in the `MyStackGeneric` class.  The class should do one thing only, which is serve as the base for implementing concrete stacks.  Input and output should be handled by the users of the class, who could do the correct parsing/conversion for the input data.

Or, to put it another way, converting input data to match the generic type requires information (the concrete parameter type) that is not available to the `MyStackGeneric` class because of type erasure.  You *could* put concrete versions of `readInput()` in your concrete classes. For `MyStackInteger` those lines would become

```
        if (s2.matches("[+-]?\\d+")) {
            push(Integer.valueOf(s2));
```

But that still violates the single-responsibility principle.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't actually see that error. I'm running this on Netbeans and this is the only error that pops up:
run:
2 2 + p

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
 at MyStackInteger$1.plus(MyStackInteger.java:9)
 at MyStackGeneric.binaryOperator(MyStackInteger.java:161)
 at MyStackInteger.binaryOperator(MyStackInteger.java:5)
 at MyStackGeneric.readInput(MyStackInteger.java:96)
 at MyStackInteger.readInput(MyStackInteger.java:5)
 at MyStackInteger.main(MyStackInteger.java:10)

Comment: The Type-Safety message is a COMPILER warning, not a runtime error. You'll see it as some sort of marker in the source view.  I use Eclipse so I don't know what it looks like in NetBeans.

Comment: I uploaded what it looks like on my computer to this link [link](http://imgur.com/a/iu6X3) Usually there is a light bulb or red sign in the highlighted area if there is an issue.

Comment: What happens if you hover over the yellow highlight in the line numbers?

Comment: I added that highlight myself to illustrate where the issue would be. I actually tried to remove the (E) but then Netbeans recommended I [typecast s2 to (E)](http://imgur.com/a/d9Cd7). When I run the program, everything works fine up to the point where I try to make an arithmetic operation on two variables from the stack.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not NetBeans complains, you CANNOT DO WHAT YOU ARE TRYING TO DO.  That cast will never work and cannot be made to work.  That method does not belong in that class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122881/discussion-between-daniel-and-jim-garrison).